# How to automatically mount 3 TrueCrypt volumes on OSX after login

Tags: macos, passwords, encryption, truecrypt

As the title say I would like to automatically mount 3 volumes after logging into OSX. I saved my 3 volumes to the favorite volumes.

I tried the –-auto-mount=favorites parameter from here: http://www.myiphoneadventure.com/os-x/truecrypt-automator-automatically-mounted-encrypted-drives-in-os-x

so my script looks like this:

/Applications/TrueCrypt.app/Contents/MacOS/TrueCrypt –-auto-mount=favorites

It does seem to load at startup with the dialog for the password, but then gives me an error saying the script has an error or something.

This didn't seem to help me either:

http://www.medienvilla.com/index.php?id=236#linux_prep

So I have 2 questions:

1. How do I make this happen so that my favorite volumes that are already saved in TC to load without errors? Copy & Paste script would be awesome, as I'm not a programmer.
2. How would I get rid of the potential admin password before the actual volume password?

Answer (score 0):

To make TC load on startup and to automount your favorite drives/partitions do the following:

1. Right-click the mounted volume in the drive list in the main TC window
2. Select ‘Add to System Favorites’.

The System Favorites Organizer window should appear now.

3. In this window, enable the option ‘Mount system favorite volumes when Windows starts’
4. click OK.

Next boot TC will start and if the drives are loaded it will ask you for the password for each favorite drive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but you're refering to the Windows version. I'm on OSX. Even though you can add volume to your favorite, there is NO option to mount them automatically like on windows. That has to be done via a script. That's what I need the code here http://www.myiphoneadventure.com/os-x/truecrypt-automator-automatically-mounted-encrypted-drives-in-os-x didn't seem to work.